# Winforms on .Net Framework 4.7 or only on .Net Framework 2.0 is compatible with Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono

Based on info here https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/   which is the highest version of Winforms (based on which .Net Framework) is supported by Mono? I believe infos in these two citations on the same page are contradicting:

"The easiest way to describe what Mono currently supports is:
**Everything in .NET 4.7 except WPF, WWF**, and with limited WCF and limited ASP.NET async stack." In my understanding WWF resolves to Windows Workflow Foundation, so this means that Winforms on .Net Frameork 4.7 is supported by Mono. This should be nice and clear. But then:

"**.NET 2.0 Checkmark at: Winforms/System.Drawing 2.0**" As Winforms is not mentioned as implemented on any later versions of .NET this leads me to think that no later version of Winforms .Net Framework is supported then .Net Framework 2.0

Comment: WinForms 2.0 is [VS Whidbey](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2004/01/01/winforms-gain-ground-in-whidbey.aspx?admgarea=features&m=1). Still there today in .Net Framework (though a lot of stuff has been tweaked in the meanwhile). .Net 4.7 of course includes WinForms. Mono doesn't port Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF).

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea With so many options out there, WinForms on Mono shouldn't be considered.